# Swift Reverse Geocoding get name of state always in same language

Tags: swift

i need to get the name of the state where the user is. To do so i created the following method:

```
func getState(){
    if location != nil{
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location)
        { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {}
            else
            {
                let pm = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark)

                var subThoroughtare:String = ""
                var thoroughfare:String = ""
                var subLocality:String = ""
                var subAdministrativeArea:String = ""
                var postalCode:String = ""
                var country:String = ""

                if pm.subThoroughfare != nil {subThoroughtare = pm.subThoroughfare!}
                if pm.thoroughfare != nil {thoroughfare = pm.thoroughfare!}
                if pm.subLocality != nil {subLocality = pm.subLocality!}
                if pm.subAdministrativeArea != nil {subAdministrativeArea = pm.subAdministrativeArea!}
                if pm.postalCode != nil {postalCode = pm.postalCode!}
                if pm.country != nil {country = pm.country!}
                let state = pm.administrativeArea;

                self.filterDataSet(state: state!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the name of the state is always in the phones language, but i need it in english. How can i set it to english as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variation of `CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation()` that takes a parameter `preferredLocale`. Try passing in US English as the locale. That should do it.

Comment: sorry i cannot set it to us or english. Could you be more specific

Comment: @MarkusGerlach You first create a locale: `let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")`. Then pass it to the function: `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: locale) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in ...`

Comment: @MarkusGerlach and change `let pm = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark)` to `if let pm = placemarks?.first {`
`

Comment: @LeoDabus good point. That was a double-whammy for crashing as written.

Comment: another point is he checks all properties (except the state which is the only one he needs) against nil instead of unwrapping them. `if let state = placemarks?.first?.administrativeArea {` `self.filterDataSet(state: state)` `}`